# Simplify url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I need just simplify url in my rails app.
`/nature` instead `/categories/nature`

My `routes.rb`:

> match 'categories/:id' => 'categories#show'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match ':id' => 'categories#show'
```

This will make any request to '/something' to categories controller with show action though so you have to take that into account.

If I were you I'd do it more like that:

```
match ':id' => 'categories#show',:constraints => { :id => /nature|sports|architecture|people|.../ }
```

This way you can still use '/something' routes as you wish as long they don't match any of the available categories.

Comment: Thank you! It works! But I forget about `link_to` in my view(it was like this `"/category/#{c.id}"`)